# how to implement a timer (including milliseconds) into an app

Tags: ios, timer

So I am creating a basic game for iOS (using exclusively objective-c) Xcode and have looked all over but cannot seem to find any tips for a starting point. I just want to time the player while the game is playing and have the scene all set up but can't figure out how to generate a timer just to display the time as the player plays and then pass it to my game over scene when the game finishes.

any tips or help what so ever would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Search for `NSTimer` on this site.

Comment: Also, here is [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/) for NSTimer that @trojanfoe rightfully suggested.

Comment: Thanks this did actually help! I figured it out. The issue wasn't with my method it was that I wasn't adding the object into my scene..... the simplest errors are sometimes the hardest to spot.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 parts to this. One part is to have a repeating event to display new info (elapsed time) to the user. For that NSTimer is perfect. See the comments from trojanfoe and tnev for info on `NSTimer`.

The second part is calculating the amount of time that's elapsed.

For that I recommend the following:

Create an instance variable of type NSTimeInterval (a double) in your view controller class:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSTimeInterval startTime;
```

In your game start method, save the current time interval:

```
-(void) gameSart
{
  self.startTime = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
  //Also start an NSTimer to display elapsed time.
}
```

Then code to calculate elapsed time (or total time):

```
NSTimeInterval elapsed = 
  [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] - self.startTime; //in seconds
//Display elapsed time to a label, perhaps formatted as minutes/seconds.
```